# Rails different output if block is given inline or over multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble finding out what I did wrong or how to achieve the same result.
What I'm trying to do is to print the array @attributes in a rails view.

This is not working:

```
<% @attributes.each do |element| %>
<%= puts element.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

But this is:

```
<%= @attributes.each { |element| puts element.to_s }%>
```

I've also played around with putting everything in the first statement in <%= %> without any success. 
Aren't those two statements exactly the same?

Also, if you could help me out - how would you iterate over the array and insert a new line after each item?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: `puts` isn't doing anything in either of your examples. Your second example only works because you're doing `<%= @attributes.each { ... } %>` and `each` returns `@attributes`, so this is fundamentally identical to simply writing `<%= @attributes %>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`puts` does not actually output to the ERB buffer. It outputs to STDOUT and returns nil. If you want to iterate through the records and output you would do it by:

```
<% @attributes.each do |element| %>
  <%= element.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

The `<%= %>` ERB tags output the return value of the expression into the buffer. If you wanted to do this with a non-printing ERB expression you would need to use [`concat`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

```
<% @attributes.each { |element| concat element.to_s } %>
```

> Aren't those two statements exactly the same?

No. The output is actually the same as:

```
<% @attributes.each do |element| %>
  <%= nil %>
<% end %>
```

And

```
<%= @attributes %>
```

Comment: Thanks max, you just solved a three-day headache. Out of curiosity - where can I find this stuff? Is this just something you kind of now? Or do I need to google for some specific / exact wording ?

Comment: The [ERB documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) is good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses the `ERB` templates to render the views or say generate `html` documents for the browsers amongst others.

`ERB`copies the text portions of the template directly to the generated document, and only processes code that is identified by markers. There are mostly two types of markers `<% %>` and `<%= %>`.

A tag with an equals sign indicates that the enclosed code is an expression and that the renderer should substitute the code element with the result of the code (as a string) when it renders the template.

Tags without the equals sign denote that the enclosed code is a scriptlet. Each scriptlet is caught and executed, and the final result of the code is then injected into the output at the point of the scriptlet.

```
<% @attributes.each do |element| %>
  <%= puts element.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

With your example above you're telling the renderer to put whatever is the result of the expression in the second line, which is the output of the element.

Whereas here `<%= @attributes.each { |element| puts element.to_s }%>` you are asking rendered to put the `@attributes` object/variable along with the individual output of whatever is inside in `@attributes` variable which explains the difference in your output results.

PS you can avoid both `puts` and `to_s` from `<%= puts element.to_s %>` because whatever is inside `<%= %>` gets to the HTML document as a string itself.